# iptables-restore failing to load my rules

Tags: 10.10, server, iptables

I've been searching around for some time now, but nothing solves my problem.
I'm setting up a mail server, but when writing to the iptables, I get an error:

iptables-restore: line 2 failed.

I'm trying to use the following /etc/iptables.test.rules:

```
# Allows SMTP access
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT

# Allows pop and pops connections 
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT

# Allows imap and imaps connections 
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
```

After this, I'm issuing the following command:

```
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.test.rules
```

However I get returned this:

```
iptables-restore: line 2 failed.
```

I don't know what the problem is. Can anyone clarify?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 LTS

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because that file is not in the expected format. You should add your rules manually the first time, then use `iptables-save` to get a file in the expected format.

However it's quite simple to "mimic" the format that iptables-restore expects.

Add a line with just `*filter` at the top of the file.

Add a line with just `COMMIT` at the bottom.

So you end up looking like this:

```
*filter    

# Allows SMTP access
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT

# Allows pop and pops connections 
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT

# Allows imap and imaps connections 
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

There's a few other snippets it should have too but that should make it work. After doing this, you can use `iptables-save >filename` to get the fully correctly formatted save file into `filename`.

Note that if you do use `iptables-save` your comments in the file will be lost (it will replace the entire file with its own similar formatted one).

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

then start/restart your `iptables` Service